# How can I read two columns of numbers in a text file?

Tags: c, file

My .txt looks like this for example:

> 1.0  2.0
>
> 1.0  1.0
>
> 2.0  3.0
>
> 2.0  1.0

I want to run through this file using each line when its needed. To explain I have an equation (L = Ax + B) which I need to calculate for different x's. Is there a way to read each line in the file seperately, taking A and B at that line. So the first term of L will use the first A and B.

I haven't done this before. This is what I know already:

```
void coefficients(double *A, double *B) {
    FILE *infile;
    
    if(2!=fscanf(infile,"%lf %lf",A, B)) {
        printf("Error reading parameters from file\n");
        exit(1);
        
    }
    fclose(infile);
}
```

And then calling this in int_main:

```
    double A;
    double B;
    // Read in from file; 
    coefficients(&A, &B);
```

Comment: You should use `perror("Error reading parameters from file");` instead of `printf("Error reading parameters from file\n");`

Comment: Also you have various small mistakes, like an extra comma and not opening `infile`, and using `micro` and `elastic` instead of `A` and `B`.

Comment: You can just use a loop: `while(2==fscanf(infile,"%lf %lf",micro, elastic)) {}` but remember to ignore the first line prior: `while(getchar() != '\n') {}`

Comment: @S.S.Anne Thank you. Where do I put that line, is it in the int_main where I use it. Can I still do the void part. And do I have to write coefficients(&A, &B); still and then write that later.

Comment: You replace the `if` in `coefficients` with the `while`. You might fix the variable names though, because I posted the comment before you made your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a file with potential blank lines and potential lines that contain something other than the pair of `double` values you are looking for, you are much better off reading each line into a buffer and the parsing the wanted values from the buffer with `sscanf` rather than attempting to read directly with `fscanf`. This way a line of input is consumed on each read and you don't have to worry about what remains in your input stream depending on the conversion specifiers used.

Further, in order to read multiple values into `A` and `B`, both `A` and `B` must be arrays of `double` (or an allocated block of memory that can hold multiple `double` values)

For example in `main()` can declare:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    double a[MAXC] = {0}, b[MAXC] = {0};    /* arrays of MAXC doubles */
```

Now you have storage for `1024` double values. Your `coefficient` function that reads the `double` values should return the number of values read. It should also take the open and validated `FILE*` stream as a parameter. (if the file cannot be opened in validated in the caller -- there is no reason to make the function call to attempt the read to begin with)

Putting that together you could do:

```
size_t coefficients (FILE *fp, double *a, double *b)
{
    char buf[MAXC];         /* buffer for reading each line */ 
    size_t ncoeff = 0;      /* number of coefficient pairs read */

    while (ncoeff < MAXC && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))  /* read each line */
        /* if it contains 2 double values */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%lf %lf", &a[ncoeff], &b[ncoeff]) == 2)
            ncoeff++;       /* increment counter */

    return ncoeff;          /* return total count of pairs read */
}
```

A short example putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

size_t coefficients (FILE *fp, double *a, double *b)
{
    char buf[MAXC];         /* buffer for reading each line */ 
    size_t ncoeff = 0;      /* number of coefficient pairs read */

    while (ncoeff < MAXC && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))  /* read each line */
        /* if it contains 2 double values */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%lf %lf", &a[ncoeff], &b[ncoeff]) == 2)
            ncoeff++;       /* increment counter */

    return ncoeff;          /* return total count of pairs read */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    double a[MAXC] = {0}, b[MAXC] = {0};    /* arrays of MAXC doubles */
    size_t n = 0;                           /* count of doubles returned */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(n = coefficients (fp, a, b))) {   /* validate coeff pairs read */
        fputs ("error: no double values read from file.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)  /* output coefficients */
        printf ("a[%zu] : %.1f   b[%zu] : %.1f\n", i, a[i], i, b[i]);
}
```

(you can adjust the size of the arrays as needed)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/coeffpairs.txt
    A B

    1.0 2.0

    1.0 1.0

    2.0 3.0

    2.0 1.0
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readcoeff dat/coeffpairs.txt
a[0] : 1.0   b[0] : 2.0
a[1] : 1.0   b[1] : 1.0
a[2] : 2.0   b[2] : 3.0
a[3] : 2.0   b[3] : 1.0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: You should use fgets+sscanf *only* if you care about verifying that the file is in the format of two numbers per line and nothing else.  Otherwise, just use fscanf directly.    If you do you fgets+sscanf, you should also check that there isn't anything else on each line and output a reasonable error message if there is -- use the `%n` specifier to sscanf to ensure that you consumed the entire line.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, but for the new C programmer, dealing with the *matching failures* for the heading line and *input failure* for every empty line, emptying `stdin` up through the next newline just introduces additional caveats and you would end up looping with `fgetc` or calling `fgets` to consume the remainder of any offending line. It is *6 to-one* or *1/2 dozen to another*. If you already know how to handle the caveats, you can squeak a little more efficiency out of `fscanf`, but here every other line was empty, so you hit as many *input failures* as you do good reads.

Comment: empty lines will just be ignored by fscanf -- if you don't care about the details of the formatting (just "there's numbers in the file and nothing else"), then fscanf is much simpler.

Comment: Yes, good point, it's just *whitespace* at that point for `fscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to read a text file(file.txt) to a char array (`buffer`) line by line by using [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) then parse it with [`sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to find double value in it.

***Code***

```
double a=0;
double b=0;

int bufferLength = 1024;
char buffer[bufferLength];

FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if (!fp){
    printf("Cant open file\n");
    return -1;
}

while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)) {
    //printf("%s\n", buffer);   
    if (2==sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &a,&b)){
        printf("a: %f   b: %f\n", a,b);
    }
}

fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.  If you just want to read the data and don't care what happens when it is not in the form of two columns, you can just read it with fscanf in a loop:

```
double  A, B;
while(fscanf(fp, "%ld%ld", &A, &B) == 2) {
    // do something with A and B
```

This will read *any* sequence of numbers in the file -- maybe in two columns or all on one line or randomly split between lines with blank lines, and will stop when it gets to anything that is not a number (or the end of the file, and will ignore any odd single number at the end).

If on the other hand you want to verify that the numbers are two per line and no blank lines, you can use fgets+sscanf:

```
char line[256];    
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
    double A, B;
    int end;
    if (sscanf(line, "%ld%ld %n", &A, &B, &len) == 2 && line[end] == 0) {
        // got a line with (just) a pair of numbers
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "malformed input line: %s", line);
    }
}
```

If you also want to check that the numbers are lined up in columns, that is a bit trickier.  You can check for left- or right-aligned columns pretty easily

```
char line[256];
int a_col = -1, b_col = -1, lineno = 0;    
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
    double A, B;
    int a_right, b_right, end;
    ++lineno;
    if (sscanf(line, "%ld%n%ld%n %n", &A, &a_right, &B, &b_right, &len) == 2 && line[end] == 0) {
        // got a line with (just) a pair of numbers
        if (a_col >= 0 && (a_col != a_right || b_col != b_right)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "columns on line %d not lined up with previous line\n", lineno);
        }
        a_col = a_right;
        b_col = b_right;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "malformed input on line %d", lineno);
    }
}
```